# IP Camera Application for Android

Tags: android, webcam

I am looking for an Android application for streaming a live camera view over the web, essentially turning the device into an IP camera.

**Must Haves:**

- Ability to control device 'flash' (built-in LED)
- Audio and Video
- Motion detection
- Multiple device support
- Auto-focus

**Nice to Haves:**

- Online hosting (must be optional)
- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) integration
- Image and/or video capture
- Ability to stream into VLC (dedicated stream URL)
- Light weight (processor & battery efficient)

**Example:** [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en) (lacking multi-device support)

**Clarification:** This is a separate question from [IP Camera Viewer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30543/ip-camera-viewer) as this is the server side of a client server system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IP Camera Viewer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30543/ip-camera-viewer)

Comment: @Baronz These questions are certainly not duplicates, as they ask for two pieces of software with different uses (one to send an IP video feed and one to receive it).

Answer (score 1):

## [Perch](https://getperch.com/)

It's an Android app that streams a live camera view to the web. It has multiple features on top of your "must-haves" that make it a great piece of software.

[image: screenshot]

### Features

- Video streams hosted on Perch's servers
- Very quick setup. It's almost grab and go. Install the app, register an acccount and enable recording. Definitely less than 5 minutes.
- App is straightforward to use with well thought out design
- Web app available so footage can be viewed from another mobile device or from a computer
- Can specify areas for motion detection so movement in non-specified areas will not trigger an alert

### Things To Note

- You must register an account with Perch.
- Live video streams and video archives are stored on Perch's servers. **There is currently no offline storage option** to store the footage locally.
- All video is automatically recorded. There is no option to disable saving of the video footage on Perch's servers.
- Perch is currently in beta
- Perch requires Android 4.0 or higher

Comment: While this sounds viable, it raises several security concerns, plus the lack of being able to download the recording seems a problem. Must you use Perch's IP camera software or can you feed it an MJPEG stream.