# IP Camera Viewer

Tags: windows, video

I am looking for software, a web application, or website for viewing IP camera streams from an Android device.

**Must Haves:**

- Ability to view/connect multiple streams at once
- Ability to load sound with the stream (MJPEG+WAV, Flash, etc.)
- Ability to record the stream locally

**Nice to haves:**

- Ability to control Android device's LED
- Ability to send audio to be played through speaker
- Multi-platform compatible (esp. Windows 10, Android, and Linux)
- Interface customizability

**More Info:**

I am using [IP Cam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en) to stream video and audio from my Android device, but am open to other app suggestions here: [Question: IP Camera Application for Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30540/ip-camera-application-for-android)

**Clarification:** This is a separate question from [IP Camera Application for Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30540/ip-camera-application-for-android) as this is the client side of a client server system.

Comment: How do you suggest the server-side to run on Windows non-stop 24 hours? Anyway, the same site from the post below [offers the alternatives](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/RelatedProjects?sortcol=2;table=1;up=1#sorted_table) which you could try.

Answer (score 3):

I monitor 8 cameras with a linux daemon called **motion**  It reads the capture card for 5, and streams data from three netcams.  It also supports USB cameras, subject to bandwidth.

Then I can view an html page which contains 8 HTML links like this

```
<img src="http://server:9871"> <br>
<img src="http://server:9872">
```

and I can see all cameras in my browser.

Downsides, I have not explored audio because recording audio without consent in my country would be illegal.

Downside - you'll need a linux box, physical if you need USB or capture cards, or a virtual would be okay if you just use network cameras.

The streams are recorded in the linux server not on the viewing device, and for me 90 days of 8 cameras footage is around 800GB to 1TB.

Good side is all you need is a web browser, so this works in any modern web browser

- http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuide
- Try the #motion IRC channel on freenode

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation and including all necessary information (the IRC channel is an interesting note). It's unfortunate that Motion is Linux only though, as I primarily use Windows 10 and Android.